# How can I keep up with demand?

Tags: epic-astro-story

In Epic Astro Story, I am having a hard time keeping with with the demand of visiting aliens for goods when those goods require either refined goods (which is a bit easier to tackle) or when a product requires multiple resource types.

My current attempt at solving this has a level 25 citizen working exclusively on making Home Theater Seats. This requires three of Iron ore and three Rare Metals. I have four mining platforms, two for iron and two for the metals. For workers on the mines I have six citizens so there is always some one waiting to restock a mine. For visitor access I have two landing pads, two tourist attractions and a single Resort hotel.

About every third or fourth visiting alien leaves with only visiting the tourist attraction. I simply can not keep up with how fast they want things. This also goes for just about any material made at a factory though things that require less materials do seem easier as they spend less time toting resources around. The layouts that I have pretty much put the resources across the street from where they are needed. This keeps most travel time to Out of one building and Into target building then back again.

Is this just how the game goes? Is it impossible to build an infrastructure that can meet demand?